# Проверка строки на отсутствие текста

Tags: строки, c++

Здравствуйте.

Есть большая строка типа string, с различными словами и разделителем в виде ":" 
Пример: "Word:20numbers:567"  
Копирую во временную строку первое слово и проверяю на то является ли оно числовым, затем второе и третье. То есть текстовых символов в слове быть не должно. 
В результате останется только 567.

Вопрос: Каким алгоритмом проверить это условие. Не проверять же ифами каждый символ слова, является ли он буквой или нет.

Comment: Во-первых и проверить недолго, во-вторых -- регекспом можно проверить (класс regex)

Comment: Если пробелов (табуляций) не должно быть, то достаточно проверить первый символ в каждом "слове", вызвав isdigit().

И, кстати,  @BlackOverlord, а **зачем копировать?**.

Comment: Черт, все таки неправильно прочел вопрос. Естественно все символы надо проверять в isdigit().

Comment: @avp: (не могу больше комментировать в ответе, напишу сюда.) Вообще-то моя ссылка на cplusplus.com не очень хороша, этот сайт пользуется дурной славой. На cppreference.com никаких замечаний о локали [нет](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), так что судя по всему, в (4) я не прав.

Comment: Копировать надо, потому как строка с одним словом подается на функцию.

Comment: а нельзя изменить функцию, чтобы она работала с двумя аргументами?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пусть в `s` строка, которую нужно проверить на наличие не цифровых символов.

```
size_t found=s.find_first_not_of("1234567890");
if (found!=string::npos) {
    std::cout << "ой, есть не цифровой символ " << s[found] << " в позиции " << found << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Все ок!" << std::endl;
}
```

Код простой, легко модифицируется.

Answer (score 2):

Регулярные выражения Вам в помощь. В стандартной библиотеке с++ их поддержка не реализована. Но есть масса других библиотек с их поддержкой. В частности, `Boost`. 
Например, вот это у нас пример использования простейшего  регулярного выражения с проверкой того, состоит ли строка из цифр:

```
boost::regexp  exp("d\+")
```

Comment: Стандартные библиотеки -- они разные. Для каждого стандарта -- своя. В c++11 вроде должон быть.

Comment: Вам виднее, наверное - я на C++ пишу не профессионально, поэтому тех или иных тонкостей не знаю

Answer (score 1):

[Регулярные выражения в C++: Использование библиотеки PCRE. (pcre gcc cpp regex)](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/pcre_cpp.txt.html)
не плохая статья

Comment: мне кажется, привлекать тяжёлую артиллерию в виде регулярных выражений для такой тривиальной задачи -- стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Как там говорится? "Кремний дёшев, програмисты дороги"?

Comment: Правильно мыслите, @VladD. 

А мне вот уже надоело писать такие замечания к подобным ответам.

Comment: @avp, вот я совершенно не понимаю людей, которые к тривиальным задачам подходят с использованием reg-exp.

Понимаю было бы вам неизвестно что в строке, или набор искомых символов огромный, или еще чего в таком духе, но не така же простотень...

Comment: Ох.

    int isNumber;
    for(char *c=MainStr.c_str(), isNumber = (*c !=0); *c && (isNumber &= isdigit(*c++););

Пришлось подправить для пустой строки. А regexp будет

    ^\d+$

Почувствуйте разницу

Comment: @alexlz, а весь код вокруг `^\\d+$` для анализа? 

Кстати, еще несколько символов в написанном Вами `for` и число уже прочли в int. По сути это код atoi().

Comment: @alexlz: а почему так сложно? Вы спустились до чистого C. Вот в ответе @KoVadim'а всё гораздо проще и прозрачнее.

Comment: @VladD, раззадорили меня тут. Если хотите совсем просто, то 

    #define isItNum(str,v) ({char *e; (v) = strtol((str),&e,10); !*e);})

Строка цифр завершается нулем. Перед цифрами могут быть пробелы и табуляции.

Естественно, в переменной v будет значение числа или 0.

Comment: @avp: хм, мне кажется, этого недостаточно. (1) надо проверять `e`: если не ноль, в строке были нецифры за цифрами. Или цифры, но число не влезло в long. (2) `strtol` игнорирует начальные пробелы, а автор вопроса -- нет. (3) `strtol` позволяет иметь знак, а автор вопроса -- нет. (4) для текущей локали отличной от "C" функция может не отвергать локаль-специфические символы. Простите за занудство.

Comment: @VladD, это д.б. под требования автора

    #define isItNum(str,v) ({char *e; (v) = 0; isdigit(*(str))? (v) = strtol((str),&e,10), !*e: 0;})

По поводу Ваших замечаний:

1) `e` проверяется, легко заметить если в конце строки не 0, то результат 0 (не число)

2, 3) добавили, что первый символ д.б. цифра (а не знак, пробел и т.п.)

4) причем здесь локаль??? IMHO арабские цифры они всюду одинаковы. Если не согласны - **приведите пример (код в студию)**.

Comment: @avp: хм, а как насчёт (1) для строки, состоящей из ста единиц? (2), (3) согласен. Насчёт (4) код привести не смогу; я ориентировался вот на [это описание](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/):

> For locales other than the "C" locale, additional subject sequence forms may be accepted.

Я не уверен, встречается ли этот случай на практике. Например, для какой-нибудь китайской локали могут ли китайские традиционные формы записи ([零, 一, 二, 三](http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html)) пролезть через `strtol`?  Хотя автору вопроса возможно именно это и нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, напрямую к вопросу не относится, но в процессе обсуждения написались три обертки для strtol(). Наберусь нахальства предложить здесь, может кому и пригодятся.

Некоторое описание приведено ниже (после **update**).

```
// avp 2012   macro for strtol()
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define isItNum(str,v) ({char *s = (char *)(str), *e; (v) = 0;  \
      isdigit(*s)? (v) = strtol(s,&e,10), !*e: 0;})

#define IsItNum(str,v,chrs) ({char *s = (char *)(str),  \
        *c = (char *)(chrs), *e;                        \
      (v) = strtol(s,&e,10);                            \
      e == s? 0:                                        \
        *e == 0? 1:                                     \
        (c && *c)? strchr(c, *e)? 1: 0                  \
        :0; })

#define IsItNumEptr(str,ptr,v,chrs) ({char *s = (char *)(str), \
        *c = (char *)(chrs), *e;                               \
      (v) = strtol(s,&e,10); (ptr) = e;                        \
      e == s? 0:                                               \
        *e == 0? 1:                                            \
        (c && *c)? strchr(c, *e)? 1: 0                         \
        :0; })

main ()
{
  int n, x[2] = {5,6};
  char *str = " 87";

#ifdef __cplusplus
  std::cout << "Hi, С++\n";
#endif

  printf ("isItNum\n[%s] Num: %s %d\n","123 ", isItNum("123 ",n)? "yes":"no",n);
  n = isItNum(str,x[0]);
  printf ("isItNum\n[%s] Num: %s %d\n",str,n ? "yes":"no",x[0]);
  n = isItNum(str+1,*(x+1));
  printf ("isItNum\n[%s] Num: %s %d\n",str+1, n? "yes":"no",x[1]);

  str = "z\t a\t+1234,";
  n = IsItNum(str,x[0],"\n\r\t ;,])");
  printf ("IsItNum\n[%s] Num: %s %d\n",str, n? "yes":"no",x[0]);
  str = " \t \t+1234 ";
  n = IsItNum(str,x[0],NULL);
  printf ("IsItNum\n[%s] Num: %s %d\n",str, n? "yes":"no",x[0]);

  char *ept;
  str = "\t \t+1234,-";
  n = IsItNumEptr(str,ept,x[0],"\n\r\t ;,])");
  printf ("IsItNumEptr\n[%s] ept<%s> Num: %s %d\n",
      str, ept, n? "yes":"no",x[0]);

  str = " \t \t+1234";
  n = IsItNumEptr(str,ept,x[0],NULL);
  printf ("IsItNumEptr\n[%s] ept<%s> Num: %s %d\n",
      str, ept, n? "yes":"no",x[0]);

  exit(puts("End") == EOF);
}
```

Табуляции конечно сползли...

Результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc isnum.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
isItNum
[123 ] Num: no 123
isItNum
[ 87] Num: no 0
isItNum
[87] Num: yes 87
IsItNum
[z   a  +1234,] Num: no 0
IsItNum
[       +1234 ] Num: no 1234
IsItNumEptr
[       +1234,-] ept<,-> Num: yes 1234
IsItNumEptr
[       +1234] ept<> Num: yes 1234
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

**UPDATE**

Немного подправил и решил кратко описать макросы. Теперь можно использовать и в С++. Необходимо подключать файлы stdlib.h, string.h и ctype.h

Все три макроса возвращают 1, если в строке число (иначе 0). Все преобразуют цифры (десятичные) в строке **`str`** и помещают его в переменную **`v`**. Определение, содержит ли строка **`str`** число, происходит по описываемым ниже правилам.

Если представить, что это функции, то им (примерно) соответствуют прототипы:

```
int isItNum (const char *str, long &v);
```

**`str`** должна начинаться с цифры и после цифр должен идти нулевой байт.

```
int IsItNum(const char *str, long &v, const char *chrs);
```

В **`str`**  до первой цифры могут идти "пробельные" (пробел, табуляция и т.п.) символы, непосредственно перед числом может быть знак. Т.е. поведение точно соответствует *`strtol()`*. Если **`chrs`** `NULL` или `""`, то после цифр должен идти нулевой байт. Иначе в строке **`chrs`** находятся символы, любым из которых число может заканчиваться. Число всегда может заканчиваться нулевым байтом.

```
int IsItNumEptr(const char *str, char *&ptr, long &v, const char *chrs);
```

Этот макрос по способу определения числа соответствует `IsItNum`. Дополнительно в переменную **`ptr`** помещается адрес байта из **`str`** (полностью аналогично аргументу *endptr* в *strtol()*), непосредственно следующий за последней цифрой числа. Если в начале **`str`** (до первой цифры) встречается недопустимый символ, то в **`ptr`** будет тот же адрес, на который указывает **`str`**.

Comment: @avp: о, спасибо, полезный код.

Comment: @VladD, там у меня комментарии кончились, поэтому отвечаю здесь.

1) сто цифр. Вы же понимаете, что не стоит пытаться потакать любым капризам. Все это обертки стандартной функции, которые упрощают (укорачивают код) программирование "стандартных" ситуаций.

Много цифр:

    [87777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777] Num: yes -1

2,3,4) сказать нечего.

В целом, думаю, путь указан. Далее каждый берет и модифицирует макросы для своей задачи.

Comment: @avp: по поводу (4) я, судя по всему, был неправ: смотрите комментарий наверху, к основному вопросу.

Comment: @VladD, да я все увидел.

Answer (score -1):

// Проверка - содержит ли строка только число? (знаковое)

```
bool isIntInString(const std::string& in_str)
{   
size_t size = in_str.size();
if(size == 0) return false;


int it = in_str.find_first_not_of("1234567890"); 

if(it != std::string::npos)     // Нашли символ, который не число
{
    if(size == 1 || size <= (it+1) || it != 0) 
        return false;           
    if(in_str.at(0) != '-') 
        return false;           

    it = in_str.find_first_not_of("1234567890", it+1);

    if(it != std::string::npos) // Нашли еще один символ, который не число
        return false;           
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Согласен, он лишний) Просто когда писал функцию, она была в другом виде, и при тестировании, случайно вышел за предел масива, поэтому поместил try catch. Сейчас в функции не возможен выход за пределы масива. P.S. убрал try .. catch().